# How to adapt this code to use getter/setter?

Tags: c#, wpf, rdlc, cil, reflection.emit

I tried and fail to adapt this code. This is dynamic class generator from assembly on C# language. I can't use DynamicObjects because RDLC report doesn't work with none class from System.Dynamic but work great with that class generated by assembly.

What I'm trying to do is to change the property definition from a private variable to a method get and set. Don't need to be a property if it work with two functions will be great.

The code below I have commented the part that I need to change.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Dynamic;

namespace PropertyBuilderExample
{
    public class MyClassParent : DynamicObject
    {
        private dynamic _hostElement;
        public dynamic ReadProperty(string name)
        {
            return hostElement[name];
        }
        public dynamic WriteProperty(string name, dynamic value)
        {
            return _hostElement[name] = value;
        }
    }
    public class MyClassBuilder
    {
        AssemblyName asemblyName;
        public MyClassBuilder(string ClassName)
        {
            this.asemblyName = new AssemblyName(ClassName);
        }
        public object CreateObject(string[] PropertyNames, Type[] Types)
        {
            if (PropertyNames.Length != Types.Length)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The number of property names should match their corresopnding types number");
            }

            TypeBuilder DynamicClass = this.CreateClass();
            this.CreateConstructor(DynamicClass);
            for (int ind = 0; ind < PropertyNames.Count(); ind++)
                CreateProperty(DynamicClass, PropertyNames[ind], Types[ind]);
            Type type = DynamicClass.CreateType();

            return Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        }
        private TypeBuilder CreateClass()
        {
            AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(this.asemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
            ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("MainModule");
            TypeBuilder typeBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType(this.asemblyName.FullName
                                , TypeAttributes.Public |
                                TypeAttributes.Class |
                                TypeAttributes.AutoClass |
                                TypeAttributes.AnsiClass |
                                TypeAttributes.BeforeFieldInit |
                                TypeAttributes.AutoLayout
                                , typeof(MyClassParent));
            return typeBuilder;
        }
        private void CreateConstructor(TypeBuilder typeBuilder)
        {
            typeBuilder.DefineDefaultConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.RTSpecialName);
        }
        private void CreateProperty(TypeBuilder typeBuilder, string propertyName, Type propertyType)
        {
            /* HELP HERE !!!!

                AT THIS PLACE THIS CODE DEFINES A PRIVATE VARIABLE TO SAVE AND SERVE THE PROPERTY DATA
                WHAT I NEED IS TO CHANGE THIS DEFINITION TO THE PARENT METHOD ON MyClassParent ReadProperty AND WriteProperty

            */
            FieldBuilder fieldBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineField("_" + propertyName, propertyType, FieldAttributes.Private);

            PropertyBuilder propertyBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineProperty(propertyName, PropertyAttributes.HasDefault, propertyType, null);
            MethodBuilder getPropMthdBldr = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("get_" + propertyName, MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.HideBySig, propertyType, Type.EmptyTypes);
            ILGenerator getIl = getPropMthdBldr.GetILGenerator();

            getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, fieldBuilder);
            getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

            MethodBuilder setPropMthdBldr = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("set_" + propertyName,
                  MethodAttributes.Public |
                  MethodAttributes.SpecialName |
                  MethodAttributes.HideBySig,
                  null, new[] { propertyType });

            ILGenerator setIl = setPropMthdBldr.GetILGenerator();
            Label modifyProperty = setIl.DefineLabel();
            Label exitSet = setIl.DefineLabel();

            setIl.MarkLabel(modifyProperty);
            setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
            setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, fieldBuilder);

            setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);
            setIl.MarkLabel(exitSet);
            setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

            propertyBuilder.SetGetMethod(getPropMthdBldr);
            propertyBuilder.SetSetMethod(setPropMthdBldr);
        }
    }
}
```

This is how to use that wonderfull class generator

```
    using System;  
    using System.Collections.Generic;  
    using System.Linq;  
    using System.Reflection;  
    using System.Reflection.Emit;  
    using System.Text;  
    using System.Threading.Tasks;  
    using PropertyBuilderExample;  
      
    namespace PropertyBuilderExample  
    {  
        class Program  
        {  
            static void Main(string[] args)  
            {  
                MyClassBuilder MCB=new MyClassBuilder("Student");  
                var myclass = MCB.CreateObject(new string[3] { "ID", "Name", "Address" }, new Type[3] { typeof(int), typeof(string), typeof(string) });  
               Type TP = myclass.GetType();  
                  
                foreach (PropertyInfo PI in TP.GetProperties())  
                {  
                    Console.WriteLine(PI.Name);  
                }  
                Console.ReadLine();  
            }  
        }  
    }
```

Comment: Have CreateProperty return an object instead of a void.

Comment: Thank you, but, what does it means... What does it changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the solution:

```
    private void CreateProperty(TypeBuilder typeBuilder, string propertyName, Type propertyType)
    {
        PropertyBuilder propertyBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineProperty(propertyName, PropertyAttributes.HasDefault, propertyType, null);
        MethodBuilder getPropMthdBldr = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("get_" + propertyName, MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.HideBySig, propertyType, Type.EmptyTypes);
        ILGenerator getIl = getPropMthdBldr.GetILGenerator();

        string methodName = "ReadProperty" + propertyType.Name;

        getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, propertyName);
        getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(MyClassParent).GetMethod("ReadProperty"));
        getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        propertyBuilder.SetGetMethod(getPropMthdBldr);
    }
```

Comment: Is this an answer or an addition to the question?

Comment: Great. Can you add any explanatory text, in the answer, to help future readers? They might find that useful.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding the code-to-generate into the target  class, like so

```
public class MyClassParent : DynamicObject
{
    private dynamic _hostElement;
    public dynamic ReadProperty(string name)
    {
        return _hostElement[name];
    }
    public dynamic WriteProperty(string name, dynamic value)
    {
        return _hostElement[name] = value;
    }

    // EDIT:
    public int ID
    {
        get { return ReadProperty("ID"); }
        set { WriteProperty("ID", value); }
    }
}
```

and displaying the resulting IL in a tool such as ILSpy, giving

```
MyClassParent.get_ID:
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldsfld      UserQuery+MyClassParent+<>o__4.<>p__0
IL_0006:  brfalse.s   IL_000A
IL_0008:  br.s        IL_002E
IL_000A:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_000B:  ldtoken     System.Int32
IL_0010:  call        System.Type.GetTypeFromHandle
IL_0015:  ldtoken     UserQuery.MyClassParent
IL_001A:  call        System.Type.GetTypeFromHandle
IL_001F:  call        Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder.Convert
IL_0024:  call        System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite<System.Func<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite,System.Object,System.Int32>>.Create
IL_0029:  stsfld      UserQuery+MyClassParent+<>o__4.<>p__0
IL_002E:  ldsfld      UserQuery+MyClassParent+<>o__4.<>p__0
IL_0033:  ldfld       System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite<System.Func<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite,System.Object,System.Int32>>.Target
IL_0038:  ldsfld      UserQuery+MyClassParent+<>o__4.<>p__0
IL_003D:  ldarg.0     
IL_003E:  ldstr       "ID"
IL_0043:  call        UserQuery+MyClassParent.ReadProperty
IL_0048:  callvirt    System.Func<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite,System.Object,System.Int32>.Invoke
IL_004D:  stloc.0     
IL_004E:  br.s        IL_0050
IL_0050:  ldloc.0     
IL_0051:  ret         

MyClassParent.set_ID:
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldarg.0     
IL_0002:  ldstr       "ID"
IL_0007:  ldarg.1     
IL_0008:  box         System.Int32
IL_000D:  call        UserQuery+MyClassParent.WriteProperty
IL_0012:  pop         
IL_0013:  ret
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I see that you understand my challenge and your solution it's what i´m afraid to have to do. I mean, is another step to create all propertys even if I did that automatically I would have to create another level in my software development way. If someone could change this demo to get and set the property from a method my solution will be perfect and awsome. I´m really grate for you try to help me.